# JavaScript UTF8 encoding

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'm trying to go through a webpage and extract some info, which I then present as a downloadable file:

```
    function handleDownload() {

        result = decode_utf8(result);

        var blob = new Blob([result], {
            type: 'text/plain;chartset=utf-8;',
        });

        saveAs(blob, 'file.csv');
    }
```

This is what I get without the `decode_utf8` call:

```
TÃ­tulo;SubtÃ­tulo;PreÃ§o;PreÃ§o por unidade;
```

The `decode_utf8` is as found [here](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.pt/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html), but I get the following error:

```
[Error] URIError: URI error
    decodeURIComponent (undefined, line 10)
    decode_utf8
    handleDownload
    (anonymous function)
```

As anybody faced this before?

Edit: By the way, the output should be:

```
Título; Subtítulo; Preço; Preço por unidade;
```

Edit: If I just `console.log` the result, it outputs correctly! Does this mean it's not an encoding problem? Maybe the file?

Comment: might try changing the decodeURIComponent() to just decodeURI()

Comment: @dandavis, I get the same exception